# How to print HTML on different PDF pages using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer in a NodeJS backend for generation of PDF reports. I have HTML code, and I need certain portions of the code to be printed on separate pages.

For example, If I have `<div><h1>Heading 1 Page 1</h1><h1>Heading 2 Page 2</h1><h1>Heading 3 Page 3</h1></div>` then I want `Heading 1 Page 1` to be on page 1. Similarly, `Heading 2 Page 2` should be on page 2 and `Heading 3 Page 3` should be on page 3.

This is the code I'm using to generate the PDF:

```js
const GENERATE_UUID = uuidv4();
const path = `test.pdf`;
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  args: ["--headless"],
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
const example_html = "<h1>Heading 1 Page 1</h1><h1>Heading 2 Page 2</h1><h1>Heading 3 Page 3</h1>"
await page.setContent(example_html, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
await page.emulateMediaType("screen");
await page.pdf({
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  path: path,
  margin: {
    top: "140px",
    right: "10px",
    bottom: "100px",
    left: "10px",
  },

  format: "A4",
});
await browser.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding the CSS properties `break-before`, `break-after` (or the deprecated `page-break-before` and `page-break-after`).

For example, to break the page before each `<h1>`:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.0.2

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const exampleHtml = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media print {
  h1 {
    break-before: page;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Heading 1 Page 1</h1>
  <h1>Heading 2 Page 2</h1>
  <h1>Heading 3 Page 3</h1>
</body>
</html>`;
  await page.setContent(exampleHtml);
  await page.emulateMediaType("print");
  await page.pdf({
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    path: "test.pdf",
    margin: {
      top: "140px",
      right: "10px",
      bottom: "100px",
      left: "10px",
    },
    format: "A4",
  });
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

See also: [Puppeteer pdf page break bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66800629/puppeteer-pdf-page-break-bug)